# My Raspberry Pi is turning off after about 3 minutes. Any ideas?

Tags: power-supply, cable

I've tried using different cables, different cards, power supplies, different HDMI cables even ... but my Raspberry Pi just shuts down after about 2~3 minutes.

- I tried with different power supplys (with different Amps > 0.8) (from China .. or even of my Nexus 7 2A power supply);
- I tried different cables (from power supply to the device);
- I also tried different SD cards, 3 brands (1 Sandisk, 1 Samsung 1 pny optima), the latter of which has been operating in a friend Raspberry Pi.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Would I had no luck with the 'Raspberry' I bought? It may have been broken? (It was from modmypi.com)

Comment: Does it just cut for a moment -- i.e., the system suddenly dies and reboots -- or do you actually see the red power led out for a while?

Comment: Have you tried a different wall socket/plug point?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche yep, I've tried others (power?) sockets.

Comment: @goldilocks just turn off (black out) video, and green led stop flashing, as well as network led stop too. just red led ON (and not flashing). sometimes I need to take and put the power cord twice for it back to work.

Comment: This might be hardware failure like bad voltage regulation. Do you still have warranty?

Comment: You say "shuts down".  Remember, we're all very literal minded here... define 'shuts down'.  Screen goes blank?  That's a power-save setting, search for a couple of my answers on that.  Doesn't respond on network (ssh?)... often ALSO a power-saving option.  All the lights go out?  That's a power supply or power regulator issue.  Can't see anything at all?  Your eyes are closed...   You need to be (much) more specific in what you're describing.  "Shuts Down" isn't enough.   Although I imagine you're seeing the power-saving console blanker kicking in.

Comment: Sorry, realized you added a comment about the issue... sounds like a power saving console blanker AND a wifi power-saving option are both kicking in.  Easy fixes, search for power-saving options here

Comment: @MatheusEduardo Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!